# Output of Matlab function is an empty array

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab function which returns an array with probability `alpha` and nothing (i.e. an empty array) with probability `1-alpha`:

```
function [binary_array_e1 , binary_array_e2 ] = croiser(binary_array_p1,binary_array_p2,alpha )

binary_array_e1=[];
binary_array_e2=[];
compt=1;

if (rand <= alpha)  
% some stuff that will put sth in binary_array_e1 and binary_array_e2
end
```

My question is: how should I manage the fact that the function could return empty arrays at the call of the function? Is something like:

```
[binary_array_e1 , binary_array_e2]=croiser(binary_array_p1,binary_array_p2,alpha);
```

be sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return an empty variable from a function call, you are totally allowed to do it and you are on the right path. Initialize your variables as empty at the beginning of the function...

```
function [binary_array_e1 , binary_array_e2 ] = croiser(binary_array_p1,binary_array_p2,alpha )

    binary_array_e1=[];
    binary_array_e2=[];

    % ...
end
```

and then just check the outcome whenever you need to do it, for example:

```
[binary_array_e1,binary_array_e2] = croiser(binary_array_p1,binary_array_p2,alpha);

if (isempty(binary_array_e1))
    % do something 1...
elseif (isempty(binary_array_e2))
    % do something 2...
else
    % do something 3...
end
```

Of course, in order to check the outcome, both variables must be returned and evaluated. But if you are returning two empty arrays in one case and two non-empty arrays in the other case, you could also check only one array:

```
if (isempty(binary_array_e1))
    % do something...
else
    % do something else...
end
```

Anyway... there are so many ways to obtain the same result. For example, you could also return a 'logical' variable that tells you immediately if your arrays have been filled with something or not, or you could return a 'struct' filled with your data in order to make everything more compact (I can elaborate on these solutions if you want). It's up to you but I see nothing wrong in your approach!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should be fine. You can later check if the output is an empty array using the function `isempty`